# P(X ≥ 10 and X is even)? - Stuck on probability question in Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

[Question found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6yha.png)

I am currently stuck on this probability question for Intro to Stat. I have tried following the multiplication rule for probabilities by multiplying P(X is even) by P(X ≥ 10) and every time my answer is off by 0.01-0.1. Am I following the wrong rule or multiplying wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a table of probabilities for all possible two-dice roll outcomes.  Which outcomes there apply to your problem... and what is the sum of all the outcomes that do apply? (Try doing it as fractions first, then see to the rounding if necessary.)

Comment: And, secondly, to see why multiplying "P(X is even) by P(X≥10)" is wrong in this case... ask yourself what the odds are for rolling "P(X is even) by P(X≥12)" **should** be from the table and compare that to the answer your method gives.

Answer (score 0):

The formula $P(A \land B) = P(A)P(B)$ is only guaranteed to be true if $A$ and $B$ are independent events. In this case, both events ("the sum is even" and "the sum is $\geq 10$") are related, so you can't assume independence and hence you can't use that formula.

You have been given a table of probabilities for individual rolls. All you need to do is take a set of those probabilities that cover the required event and combine them appropriately.